# Micronaut Server Error - No request state present. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant io.micronaut.http.HttpMethod.PRI

Tags: java, micronaut, envoyproxy

When deploying a micronaut service behind envoy we get an error associated to the handler. Is this reference to encoding?. I have tried a few options without luck. thank you.

borrower_1     | 23:10:07.038 [main] INFO  i.m.g.s.GrpcEmbeddedServerListener - GRPC started on port 50051
borrower_1     | 23:10:07.045 [main] INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup completed in 1814ms. Server Running: http://092736b9eca5:9090
borrower_1     | 23:10:35.335 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] ERROR i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Micronaut Server Error - No request state present. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant io.micronaut.http.HttpMethod.PRI
borrower_1     | io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant io.micronaut.http.HttpMethod.PRI
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:98)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
borrower_1     |    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:191)
borrower_1     |    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsServerHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsServerHandler.java:121)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.channelRead(HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.java:64)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.dequeue(FlowControlHandler.java:186)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.channelRead(FlowControlHandler.java:152)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:328)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:315)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:429)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:283)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
borrower_1     |    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:825)
borrower_1     | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant io.micronaut.http.HttpMethod.PRI
borrower_1     |    at java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:240)
borrower_1     |    at io.micronaut.http.HttpMethod.valueOf(HttpMethod.java:24)
borrower_1     |    at io.micronaut.http.netty.AbstractNettyHttpRequest.(AbstractNettyHttpRequest.java:62)
borrower_1     |    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.NettyHttpRequest.(NettyHttpRequest.java:89)
borrower_1     |    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.decoders.HttpRequestDecoder.decode(HttpRequestDecoder.java:91)
borrower_1     |    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.decoders.HttpRequestDecoder.decode(HttpRequestDecoder.java:43)
borrower_1     |    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
borrower_1     |    ... 53 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0):

Support for non standard HTTP methods was introduced in 1.3.0.M1. Please try 1.3.0.M1 and see if the issue persists.

Comment: okay, the error is now different, I'm getting null exception, it does work when envoy is out of the request path. 

borrower_1     | 01:33:03.907 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] ERROR i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: null
borrower_1     | java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: borrower_1     | 01:41:58.183 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-8] ERROR i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: null
borrower_1     | java.lang.NullPointerException: null
borrower_1     |  at io.micronaut.web.router.DefaultRouter.find(DefaultRouter.java:127)

Comment: That isn't enough of a stacktrace to determine the issue. You should file an issue on github